# Heroku, Middleman, and Contentful: Rebuilding on webhook

Tags: heroku, middleman, contentful

I'm running a Middleman site on Heroku, and using Contentful to manage content. I want to use Contentful's webhooks, and have setup my app to use the contentful_middleman gem's new webhook options (on the master branch).

It works by rebuilding the assets by running "middleman contentful --rebuild" when it receive the webhook notification on "/receive".

Is this flow doomed on heroku, because of its ephemeral file system? It seems like it, from the logs below.

If so, is there a heroku friendly way to rebuild a middleman app after it's already launched? Or will I need to switch platforms in order to use contenful webhooks in this way?

2015-11-16T21:42:05.776622+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [POST /receive] pass
2015-11-16T21:42:35.818683+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/receive" host=www.mysite.com request_id=some_id fwd="ip, another ip" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=405 bytes=367
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849264+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `each'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849253+00:00 app[web.1]: cache error: Read-only file system - /var/cache
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849435+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [POST /receive] pass
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849281+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in`call'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849268+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/storage.rb:37:in `create_store'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849270+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:149:in`invalidate'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849279+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/configuration.rb:51:in `call'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849265+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in`mkdir_p'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849257+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:242:in `fu_mkdir'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849267+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/metastore.rb:261:in`new'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849277+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849280+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/server.rb:262:in`block in run'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849256+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:242:in `mkdir'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849259+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:219:in`block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849266+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/metastore.rb:218:in `initialize'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849280+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/server.rb:375:in`process_client'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849263+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `reverse_each'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849263+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in`block in mkdir_p'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849269+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/storage.rb:18:in `resolve_metastore_uri'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849276+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in`call!'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849282+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849267+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/metastore.rb:261:in`resolve'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849269+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:34:in `metastore'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849278+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-ssl-1.4.1/lib/rack/ssl.rb:27:in`call'
2015-11-16T21:42:35.849279+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/server.rb:507:in `handle_request'

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is no way to update a static site on Heroku without making a new push. This is a limitation of Heroku itself as you said.

The alternatives are:

- Netlify (as described in other responses)
- GitHub Pages
- Forge
- and probably other static site host...

I've only tested GitHub Pages, while the others have been known to be used by others, using a kind of hackish but worked.

Let me proceed to explain:

1. Have your preview server running locally.
2. Run `ngrok http $SOME_FREE_PORT`
3. Set up webhooks to target `$YOUR_NGROK_URL:$SOME_FREE_PORT/receive`
4. Have your `/build` directory host a new Git Repo that has a `pages` remote pointing to GitHub Pages
5. Currently Webhook controllers are not configurable (but will be in a future release). In the mean time you can do the following:

```rb
    module ContentfulMiddleman
      class WebhookHandler
         def perform(*)
           super
           rebuild_and_push = <<-BASH
             bundle exec middleman contentful --rebuild && \
             bundle exec middleman build && \
             cd build && \
             git commit -ca "Webhook Triggered Rebuild" && \
             git push pages master
           BASH
           system(rebuild_and_push)
         end
       end
     end
```

This same workflow could apply to Heroku, if you automate the push to Heroku instead of GitHub Pages.

Hope this helps.

If possible, can you open an issue on our [GitHub repo](https://github.com/contentful/contentful_middleman), so that we can add a proper tutorial for this use case and get a reminder for Custom Webhook handlers?

Comment: That is being defined here: https://github.com/contentful/contentful_middleman/blob/master/lib/contentful_middleman/webhook_handler.rb. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for this @david, figured it out an hour or two after I asked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm nowhere near your level on this, and haven't tested it, but I've been looking for a similar solution before setting up a middleman app. I came across this post which uses Netlify: http://netengine.com.au/blog/simple-static-sites/

> Netlify hosts the site automatically, but you can also configure your build process to deploy elsewhere.

Again, I'm very much a starter on this, but hopefully it has some answers...

**Edit**
If you get this working, I'd love to hear how...

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend moving to [Netlify](http://netlify.com). It already has webhooks built in and will generate a URL you can add to Contentful. Whenever a new post is published on Contentful, Netlify is notified and the following build command is run...

```
middleman contentful --rebuild; middleman build --verbose
```

I've made public repo for the setup I'm running, it's still on staging for now while I do some more tests with Middleman v4, and the Contentful gem is slightly outdated as it's a fork for v4. But it should help you with how to set it up.

https://github.com/thisiscapra/thisiscapra.com/tree/staging